# Delphi: How to determine if an application is running under Win32 / Win64 and launch the 64-bit version automatically if on 64-bit?

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit

## Situation

I intend to have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of my Delphi (XE6) GUI application bundled within a Zip archive.

Note: In this question we suppose, the user extracted the whole archive, i.e. did not run the executable file directly from an archive manager.

So, let's suppose we have extracted the archive and have two files:

1. `program.exe`
2. `program64.exe`

To be crystal clear, the naming convention is that the 32-bit version does not have anything else than program name in its name, and the 64-bit version has the very same program name with the `64` suffix.

## Intention

If the user runs the 32-bit version on a 64-bit Windows machine, I want it to detect it, and close itself and run the 64-bit version instead.

## Note

In my own answer I will document all of my findings during the time I use the code, feel free to add better answer or alternative, and if it really makes some contribution, I will upvote for sure. And maybe more importantly, please do comment on specific sections you find wrong.

Comment: Why not just use a proper installer which installs the appropriate version in the first place? Why distribute a 64bit version to a 32bit machine at all when it can't even be used?

Comment: @JerryDodge Because it is a tiny application. No need for an installer. Of course you might argue, the 64-bit version is unnecessary then, I just want it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Launching other executable

First, we need a function capable of launching other executable file, my very generic example follows, you can use it for launching almost any other executable depending on your demands:

```
function LaunchExecutableFile(const ExecutableFilePath, Parameters: string; const ShowCmd: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Winapi.ShellAPI.ShellExecute(Application.MainFormHandle, 'open', PChar(StringFunctions.DoubleQuoteStr(ExecutableFilePath)), PChar(Parameters), nil, ShowCmd) > 32;
end;
```

Notes:

1. I intentionally added the optional namespaces like `Winapi.ShellAPI...` in order for you to know exactly where those functions are defined.
2. There are 32 error codes defined, that is why the function returns `True` if the result of `ShellExecute` was greater than `32`.
3. I defined function `DoubleQuoteStr`, because if there are some spaces in the path, the system would otherwise look for the file in each space delimited and therefore wrong path. It's a very simple function, and it is completely optional, it is just optimization. This, also generic, function follows:

   ```
   function DoubleQuoteStr(S: string): string;
   begin
     if (S = '') or (S = '"')
       then S := '""'
       else begin
         if S[1] <> '"' then S := '"' + S;
         if S[System.Length(S)] <> '"' then S := S + '"';
       end;
     Result := S;
   end;
   ```
4. Sadly, I am still unsure about the first `ShellExecute` `HWND` argument, more specifically if my generic way is right, feel free to correct me!

---

## Detecting 64-bit system

Second, we need a function capable of detecting 64-bit system, more specifically, if the executable is running under WOW64.

```
function IsWow64Process: Boolean;

type
  TIsWow64Process = function(AHandle: DWORD; var AIsWow64: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;

var
  hIsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process;
  hKernel32: DWORD;
  IsWow64: BOOL;

begin
  Result := False;

  hKernel32 := Winapi.Windows.LoadLibrary('kernel32.dll');
  if hKernel32 = 0 then Exit;

  try
    @hIsWow64Process := Winapi.Windows.GetProcAddress(hKernel32, 'IsWow64Process');
    if not System.Assigned(hIsWow64Process) then Exit;

    IsWow64 := False;
    if hIsWow64Process(Winapi.Windows.GetCurrentProcess, IsWow64) then
      Result := IsWow64;

  finally
    Winapi.Windows.FreeLibrary(hKernel32);
  end;
end;
```

Notes:

1. As you can see, the function loads library `kernel32.dll` and function `IsWow64Process` from it.
2. Every safety measure should be in place as for the correct result to be returned.

---

## Running the program

Finally, we need to adjust our `dpr` file.

To the variables section, add:

```
var
{$IFNDEF WIN64}
  App64: string;
{$ENDIF}
```

Enclose your main `begin` - `end` section into another `begin` - `end`.

And add something like this at the beginning:

```
{$IFNDEF WIN64}

  App64 := System.SysUtils.ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '64.exe');

  if not (ProcessFunctions.IsWow64Process and System.SysUtils.FileExists(App64) and
          ProcessFunctions.LaunchExecutableFile(App64, '', SW_SHOWNORMAL)) then

{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Better to use CreateProcess to start another process. ShellExecute is just another layer over that. Why pass SW_NORMAL? What if the 32 bit process was passed a different flag in its startup info. Shouldn't you pass that kb. Easy to do cleanly with CreateProcess. And of course you get all the startup info that way. You also neglect to pass on any command line arguments. Using CreateProcess would allow you to do away with worrying about quoting strings. And since kernel32 is guaranteed to be loaded in all processes you may as well just use GetModuleHandle.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you very much for useful information. I will try to study the CreateProcess function right away. As for the other things, let me think about them.